# typedef and template definitions

Tags: c++, typedef

Using c++98, (gcc 4.1.2), how I am supposed to achieve this?

```
template<typename T>

typedef T(*TRANSFORM)(const T&);

list<T> collect (const list<T>& list, TRANSFORM f)
{

}
```

Comment: _"gcc 4.1.2"_ That's fairly outdated. Can't you use a more current toolchain?

Comment: its a legacy project :/

Comment: Well, the answer given at the marked dupe will open you a viable way for older compilers.